# Is there a way to make a webpage run python scripts on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, webserver, raspberry-pi

Ok i know this may sound kind of noobish but I'm making a remote control raspberry pi car powered via a webpage. i have everything sorted out except im trying to find a way to make my website that's hosted on the pi run python scripts when i click a button in the webpage. is there a way to do this? possibly with a library?
please help me out.

Comment: take a look at python flask? are you asking for a light weight frame work?

Answer (score 2):

[WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) is the standard Python interface between a web server and a web application. To paraphrase [PEP333](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), it is the equivalent for Python of servlet in Java.

There are [Apache module supporting wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). As well as for most other major web servers, I assume.

For simple application, you don't need a full fledged web server though. Maybe you should take a look at some examples from the [wsgi reference implementation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The simplest and oldest way is to use CGI. Configure your web server so that when it gets a request for a particular URL (such as after clicking  on a form), it executes the python script. CGI is generic in that any executable can be run and its standard output is returned to the browser that initiated the request. (More or less - there are some headers to add to the standard output as well.)

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: A RPi isn't quite wimpy enough to resort to CGI, but it is a viable solution if you feel like it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP, you could use an AJAX call to a PHP page that runs shell_exec:

index.php:

```
<?php
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><script src="script.js"></script><title>Your Site Name</title></head><body>';
echo '<button type="button" onclick="run(\'yourscriptname.py\')">Run Your Script</button>';
echo '<br><div id="scriptResults"></div>';
echo '</body></html>';
```

script.js:

```
function run(scriptName){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "run.php?script=" + scriptName, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            document.getElementById("scriptResults").innerHTML += "<br>" + xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

run.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['script'])){
    echo shell_exec('python ' + $_GET['script']);
}
```

Please note that this is a basic framework, and that there are some things like filtering $_GET input missing.

Comment: Why use PHP to launch shell for run Python script ?

Comment: My solution doesn't cause a page reload and gives you instantaneous output from the script. It gives you the ability to click multiple buttons i.e. run multiple scripts without waiting for your browser to load a new page.

Comment: @Zulu Also, the asker didn't state what he was coding his web pages in. This is why my answer started with "If you are using PHP". I don't see why a working solution deserves a down vote.

Comment: I think Python is the better way to launch Python script. AJAX is good the good part of your architecture but not PHP.